# FileSystemWatcher sort algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, service, filesystemwatcher

I've created a simple FileSystemWatcher service that's running on my PC:

```
    public static void Run()
    {

        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = @"C:\Users\XXX\Google Drive",
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                           | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                           | NotifyFilters.FileName
                           | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,

            Filter = "*.*",
        };

        watcher.Created += OnChanged;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FooPrintClass.SendToPrinter(e.FullPath);
    }
```

As you see I'm watching a Google Drive folder. That folder is also synced on my server. From time to time a system on my server will create 2 pair of files with the same name but with diffrent type:

```
(Foo.pdf, Foo.txt)
```

Sometimes the system will create over 50 of those pairs and they all will be synced to my Google Drive folder.

So far so good, now to my problem:
My FileSystemWatcher service do work as expected, but it dosen't treat them in any sorting matter at all. 
I need my service to actually process each pair at a time.

```
Expected Result:
Foo.pdf, Foo.txt
Bar.pdf, Foo.txt

Actual Result: 
Bar.txt, Foo.pdf
Foo.txt, Bar.pdf
```

As the expected result show, I need to print the pairs in order first. 
There are many ways to implement a "queue" solution, but in my case I don't know how many files there will be. So I don't know the total of the files and therefor it'll be harder to build a queue and sorting algorithm.

Any tips?

Comment: place in an array (or suitable data structure), sort.......................

Comment: FileSystemWatcher process one file at a time. And as described I'm using Google Drive. That means that some files can be synced before others.

Comment: id expect it to send them to you as it gets them, so it could be that pairs of files, are cached and done in parallel and so theres no guarantee of the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use 3d party system for syncing files you have no control how it is done. You may have problems - no control in which order or they are synced, no guaranty that when you get a notification from your watched a file is not locked.

To easy the problem with sync order you may sync files in bundles.
If you could modify the system that creates these files, you can ZIP both files in one zip file. Having Foo.zip you can print both files in order you want.

It doesn't solve the problem with possible locking. If you could notify your service somehow about a new pair of files, you can just download these files directly from Google Drive using the API. In this case you will have full control over files and the order you get them.

Comment: Can you explain more about the locking? When can that happen? IFor now there's no way for the service to now about new pair of files.

Comment: If one application is writing or updating file (Google Drive), you may get notification from your watcher but the file is not closed at this moment. So, if the other application (your service) try to open it, it may get an error. This heavily depends on schema how the first application works with files, race conditions. The problem is that it might work fairly good on you computer with same small amount of files but under real conditions you may get into the trouble. Besides the other application may change the way it works with files in future, it may cause you problem later.

Comment: In general it is not robust approach. At least when implementing your algorithm you shouldn't rely on files are accessible immediately as you get notifications and implement some retry approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) to buffer a number of events and sort them before continuing.

An example would be something like this:

```
Observable
    .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(watcher, "Created")
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    .Subscribe(onNext);

public void onNext(IList<string>) { ... }
```

The example buffers all changes happening in 10 seconds and passes them to onNext as a list. This allows you to sort the files before doing anything else.

This ignores some edge cases like files being created right at the time when the buffer window ends. But there are multiple ways to solve those issues.

Comment: Sounds good, but if I add 10 seconds for each pair of files it will affect the performance negative

Comment: `Buffer` is just one option. You could make it so that Rx waits until the second file appears (regardless of order) and then pass both files to a function. I don't immediately have an answer on how to do it. But you could look at solutions that wait for specific key press combinations or something similar.